# Converting a code from c++ 11 to c++ 98?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in c++ and my compiler (c-free 5.0) can't compile this code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
std::string input = "slowly";

std::map<char, int> occurrences;

for (char character : input)
{
    occurrences[character] += 1;
}

for (auto& entry : occurrences)
{
    std::cout << entry.first << '=' << entry.second << std::endl;
}
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to make it work in my compiler ?

Comment: Use `std::string::iterator` and `std::map::iterator`

Comment: Search how to iterate over strings and maps.

Comment: Can you Write the full code as answer please

Comment: @user3397351 Would you put a bit more efforts in research please.

Comment: is there a reason to use this particular compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert the range-based for to loops using iterator
- Stop using `auto` and write the type manually

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "slowly";

    std::map<char, int> occurrences;

    for (std::string::iterator character = input.begin(); character != input.end(); character++)
    {
        occurrences[*character] += 1;
    }

    for (std::map<char, int>::iterator entry = occurrences.begin(); entry != occurrences.end(); entry++)
    {
        std::cout << entry->first << '=' << entry->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```